# In assembly language what does the line (r3)+ do?

Tags: assembly, memory-address, nios

I have some lines in assembly that I must be able to answer what the Effective Address (EA) of it is.
The line are...

(R3)+

+(R2)

What do the plus signs do here? I know that (R3) would have an EA = [R3], but I do not understand the + signs and cannot find an answer anywhere. Thanks.

The assembly language is NIOS II

Comment: There isn't one single assembly language, so please specify which instruction set architecture you're working with.

Comment: And once you know the architecture, I am pretty sure the addressing is documented in its manual. That said, these are probably post- and pre-increment.

Comment: Are you sure this is NIOS II? I'm looking through some docs and they don't mention any kind of expression like this

Answer (score 2):

This notation is common in assembly code on machines that do indirect addressing through registers, originally the PDP-11 but these days, I think a lot of DSPs.

What the (Rn) means typically is "indirect using the address in register N".

What +(RN) means, typically is "add one (storage unit) to register N, and then go indirect using the address in register N".   What (RN)+ means, is "go indirect on the address in register N, and when done, add one (storage unit) to register N".   -(RN) and (RN)- are analogs that "subtract one (storage unit)".

The notation, IIRC, was originally used on the PDP-11 in very early 1970s, and a variant climbed into the C language in the form of ++, -- and * operator combinations.

The PDP-11 also allowed addressing with an offset to a register, e.g., "k(RN)".  DSPs may or may not allow this.

Yes, the details should be easily found in any programming manual for the device.